# How do I connect to my Azure SQL Database using JDBC and Google Apps Script

Tags: azure, google-apps-script, jdbc

I am currently looking to create a pipeline that pushes data from a google sheet to an Azure Database table whenever the sheet gets edited.

Currently I am testing an Apps Script I am writing to connect to the database that I have set up to store the information however I keep getting errors, and am not sure what the issue in my connection string could be as the username and password are both correct.

I also have every ipv4 range allowed on the [allow list](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt) in my firewall settings.

I have currently been working off of the example that Google provided, and this is the code that is currently giving me the error:

*Failed with an error Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.*

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://{server}.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName={database};user={username}@{server};password={password};');
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error details?

Answer (score 0):

I created azure SQL database in azure portal
and I added client Ip address to the server:

I try to connect with below connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<DatabaseName>;user=<userName>@<serberName>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I got below error:

[image]

I tried with below code:

```
function  AcessaVendas () {
      var  URL='jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net:1433'
      var  USER= '<userName>'
      var  PASS= '<password>'  
      var  conn = Jdbc.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

}
```

I also try with clow code:

```
function  myFunction() {

var  conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=<databaseName>;user=<userName>@<serverName>;password=<password>;');

}
```

First I got below error:

```
"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."
```

I added fire wall rule with below Ip address:

"64.18.0.0 - 255.255.255.255"

[image]

After that My azure sql database is connected successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Is this safe to add the IP address?